# Databricks DBX and Asset Bundles: Support for Storing config files in Container/Storage Account

Tags: azure, databricks, mlops

I'm trying to deploy a Databricks workflow that is configured using `yaml` files. Currently I'm using dbx. Is there any way that, instead of using the YAML files within my project locally that is then uploaded with the `dbx deploy` command, to point the workflow to a project-specific `conf` folder mirroring the expected layout stored somewhere else? (s3 bucket, Azure Container, etc)

Using dbx version 0.18

I tried manually finding the path for the YAML file uploads, as well as digging through all of the documentation.

Comment: Once you authenticate the databricks with the storage, you can connect to either [Amazon S3](https://docs.databricks.com/en/connect/storage/amazon-s3.html) or [Azure Blob Storage](https://docs.databricks.com/en/connect/storage/azure-storage.html). Then you can access any configuration file from the storage.

Comment: Right, but then how do I tell `dbx` to look for the `deployment.yaml` file there as opposed to the project directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the `dbx` CLI to deploy a `deployment.yml` file which is in an Azure Blob storage. To quickly test it, I only generated a SAS token for the deployment file but `dbx` was unable to find the file.

Therefore, the workaround was to use `azcopy` that downloads the remote deployment file from the cloud to local storage and then executes the `dbx deploy` command.

```bash
azcopy copy "https://<account>.blob.core.windows.net/<container>/<path/to/blob>?<SAS>" "[path/to/file]deployment.yml"
dbx deploy --deployment-file <path/to/file>deployment.yml"
```

> Note: First, you need to [download the AzCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10) executable if you haven't already.

If you would like to deploy a file that is residing under a git repository, you will simple clone the repo and deploy the file:

```
git clone https://github.com/<username>/<repository>
dbx deploy --deployment-file <path/to/file>deployment.yml"
```

If it is a raw file URL, you can use the `curl` or `wget` command:

```
curl --output deployment.yml https://your-domain-name/some_folder/your_deployment.yml
dbx deploy --deployment-file <path/to/file>deployment.yml"
```

Comment: Before I mark this as the correct answer (because it does seem to solve my issue), would this work with remote URLs?

Comment: What do you mean by remote URLs? Do you mean a URL to git repository files or a general URL to some files?

Comment: @Aadi I added other alternative to download file from different remote URLs.